# Trouble Translating Regex from BBEdit to sed for Forcing Line Breaks

Tags: sed, regular-expression, freebsd, macos

I'm working on a simple method to force hard line breaks in a file at whitespaces under a margin/character limit, i.e. no line can exceed n characters and line breaks are in between words.
I have this working in BBEdit:

```
Find: (.{1,26})(\h+\R?|\R)
Replace: \1\n
```

But I can't make it work in sed (MacOS 12 zsh)

The closest I've come is:

```
sed -i .bak -E 's#(.{1,26})(\h+\R?|\R)#\1\n#g' file.txt
```

but it makes line breaks in the middle of words and it misses some lines entirely, leaving them way beyond the limit (26 in this case).
I've tried \s \t and \n in the sed command, but nothing is working. Is there a different syntax I've missed or is a different command more suitable?
Thanks.

Comment: It would be good if you have sample file or string.

Comment: Here's a sample file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rAgOJ5eCdd-u91fG2AzqD-DBGIIo8foa/view?usp=share_link

It has some short lines which will be broken by sed with:
`sed -i .bak -r 's#(.{1,26})([[:blank:]]+\n?|\n$)#\1\n#g' file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

What about just:

```
sed -r 's/(.{1,26}) /\1\n/g' file.txt
```

I have to admit that I don't understand your `(\h+\R?|\R)` - maybe there is something sophisticated going on.

Comment: I cobbled this together, so I'm not entirely clear, either, but it does have the effect of letting the line break be a match if the line is within the length limit.

I poked around some more with yours, and it almost works, except that it forces a line break on shorter lines when it finds a space, e.g. 'my cat' is broken into 2 lines. BBedit had the same result. 

I was able to still get a clean result in BBedit with just
`(.{1,26})(\h+|\n)`, but not in sed.
But I believe \R traps a wider variety of breaks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Sed acts - without special flags at least - on whole lines, so it keeps already existing newlines, which might be a sensible thing to do, if they delimit paragraphs. If you like to reformat a text, which has previously been cut at a different length, you would have to remove all \n first, but this would generate one big paragraph in total. A trick could be, to save existing paragraphs (how would they appear?) by replacing them with a reserved character - for instance a '#', if such character is not used in the text, and in a last step, repl. # by \n or <br />.

Answer (score 0):

`\h` and `\R` aren't standard. I think `\h` is `[[:blank:]]`, and `\R` [is described as](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash#Misc) `(?>\x0D\x0A|\v)`, which matches a Windows CRLF linebreak, or any vertical space. Unless there's some Unicode differences, or something else I missed.

You could use Perl for that, almost directly:

```
$ cat file.txt
Perl is a weird programming language that has taken some influences from
sed, among other things.

$ perl -pe 's/(.{1,25})([[:blank:]]+\n?|\n)/$1\n/g' < file.txt
Perl is a weird
programming language that
has taken some influences
from
sed, among other things.
```

Or with sed, you'll need to replace `\h` and `\R` with e.g. `[[:blank:]]` and `\n`. Though you're likely to need GNU sed for that `\n` to work. Also, to have sed include the trailing newline in the buffer so that it can be matched against, you'd need GNU sed's `-z` option that makes it consider NUL-separated "lines" instead, making `\n` a regular character.
You could also modify the pattern to have `(...|\n|$)`, but then you'd be adding extra newlines before any that already exist in the file.

```
$ sed -z -E 's#(.{1,40})([[:blank:]]+\n?|\n)#\1\n#g' < file.txt
Perl is a weird programming language
that has taken some influences from
sed,
among other things.
```

Though as written, the regex doesn't remove any existing newlines, as seen above.

Comment: MacOS sed won't take the `-z` switch. I am using the `-r` switch to use GNU sed. With `-r 's#(.{1,26})([[:blank:]]+\n?|\n)#\1\n#g'` it's still forcing breaks on short lines leaving a single word trailing. Otherwise, it's good. The `|$)` option does leave extra line breaks as predicted, but also breaks short lines.